# Accuracy and F1-score are 100% no matter what change is made

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have written a script that creates a Random Forest Regressor model.

The problem is that I am getting 1.00 for both accuracy and f1 measurement no mater what changes i make. Changing the model type, test size, rows and columns included in the dataset they stay the same.

I am suspicious I have done something wrong. I would like to know in which circumstances this may happen.

current results:

```
Report:
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

           1       1.00      1.00      1.00         1

   micro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00         1
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00         1

Accuracy:   1.0
```

The script is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np  
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import preprocessing

dataset = pd.read_csv("./Data/Assignment2DataSets/216037514.csv")  

print(len(dataset))

dataset["RainTomorrow"] = dataset["RainTomorrow"].astype('category')
dataset["RainTomorrow"] = dataset["RainTomorrow"].cat.codes

dataset.dropna(inplace=True)

dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset, columns=["Date", "Location", "RainToday", "WindGustDir", "WindDir9am", "WindDir3pm"], prefix=["Date", "Loc", "RTod", "WGD", "WD9am", "WD3pd"])

X = dataset.drop('RainTomorrow', axis=1)

y = dataset['RainTomorrow'] # Line must stay the same

train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.20, random_state=STUDENTNUMBER)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.20, random_state=216037514)

classifier = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 216037514)

classifier.fit(X_train,y_train) # Line must stay the same

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test) # Line must stay the same

print("Report:\n", classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
print("Accuracy:  ", accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

Comment: This sounds like you have data leakage between your features and your labels. You call `train_test_split` in your code on `X,y`, but I don't see `X` defined here

Comment: Is your X made up of full df including `RainTomorrow` column ?

Comment: X is made up of full df excluding the ```RainTomorrow``` column.